# Calling a python file within pypy

Tags: python, pypy

I recently moved to PyPy. It's amanzingly fast, but a lot of python libraries are not implemented yet. So I got a lot of home made python functions that I'd like to call within the PyPy code.

Here's my question: is there a way to call a python file or function within PyPy, and passing it some arguments ?

A code example:

I got a python module named `python_code.py` using a library not supported by PyPy, `matplotlib` for instance.

```
import matplotlib as mp

def my_custom_ploting_function(*args,**kwargs):
    some code
```

and I'd like to create a PyPY module named `pypy_code.py` like this:

```
from python_code import my_custom_ploting_function

def my_custom_pypy_ploting_function(*args,**kwargs):
    my_custom_ploting_function(*args,**kwargs)
```

But this code won't work, because PyPy cannot import the `python_code` module, because it thus will try to import `matplotlib` (which is not supported by PyPy).

Comment: What do you mean with *"passing some arguments"*? You can just use `sys.argv` with PyPY for commandline arguments. Or do you mean something else? It's not at all clear to me what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just edited the question, is it more clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to import modules and have them co-exist in the same program which would be running half CPython and half PyPy.  However, what you can do is to run your program mainly in one of the two interpreters, and consider the other one as an additional library with which you communicate at a lower level than with Python objects.

For example, if you only want to use matplotlib to display some graphic, you can from PyPy start a CPython program (with `os.system()` or the `subprocess` module) and pass it the data to display in one way or another (e.g. by sending it into a pipe).  If this is too limiting for what you want, there are other alternatives which are more involved.  You can for example load `libpython2.7.so` inside PyPy and call its C API with CFFI.  Or the reverse: embed PyPy inside CPython (as e.g. http://jitpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ).

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** run (or import) python scritps that need modules not supported by pypy.

You actually can [use matplotlib from within pypy](http://morepypy.blogspot.pt/2011/12/plotting-using-matplotlib-from-pypy.html), but it's very very hackish (and hard to do).

The simple answer here is **just use plain python**. If you're doing numeric manipulation, all intensive code should be inside `numpy`, anyway.